# Text not resizing when using AutoSizeText

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to developing in Flutter and I'm having an issue when using AutoSizeText isn't working as i thought it would.  You can see on the screen grab that my date text is overflowing.

[image]

My code for reference. If anyone could point me in the right direction of where i'm going wrong i would be gladly appreciate it!

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color(0x76168183),
                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryColor
                ],
                stops: [0, 1],
                begin: AlignmentDirectional(0, -1),
                end: AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color:
                          FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Color(0xFF168183),
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                OrderdateWidget(),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                AutoSizeText(
                                  dateTimeFormat(
                                    'MMMMEEEEd',
                                    getCurrentTimestamp,
                                    locale: FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                        .languageCode,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                      .bodyText1
                                      .override(
                                        fontFamily: 'SharpSans',
                                        color: Color(0xFF222F3A),
                                        fontSize: 32,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                        useGoogleFonts: GoogleFonts.asMap()
                                            .containsKey(
                                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                    .bodyText1Family),
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                AutoSizeText(
                                  FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
                                    'yump08wx' /* Delivery address */,
                                  ),
                                  style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                      .bodyText1
                                      .override(
                                        fontFamily: 'SharpSans',
                                        color: Color(0xFF222F3A),
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        useGoogleFonts: GoogleFonts.asMap()
                                            .containsKey(
                                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                    .bodyText1Family),
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                AutoSizeText(
                                  FFAppState().deliveryAddressName,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                      .bodyText1
                                      .override(
                                        fontFamily: 'SharpSans',
                                        fontSize: 22,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                        useGoogleFonts: GoogleFonts.asMap()
                                            .containsKey(
                                                FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                    .bodyText1Family),
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                      10, 0, 10, 0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                          .primaryBtnText,
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                            .primaryColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: AutoSizeText(
                                      FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
                                        '61jj7cic' /* Please select point of service... */,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                          .bodyText1
                                          .override(
                                            fontFamily: 'SharpSans',
                                            color: Color(0xFF222F3A),
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            useGoogleFonts: GoogleFonts
                                                    .asMap()
                                                .containsKey(
                                                    FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                            context)
                                                        .bodyText1Family),
                                          ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  5, 10, 5, 10),
                              child: Builder(
                                builder: (context) {
                                  final posGroup =
                                      FFAppState().posGroupJson.toList();
                                  return GridView.builder(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                    gridDelegate:
                                        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                      childAspectRatio: 3,
                                    ),
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    itemCount: posGroup.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, posGroupIndex) {
                                      final posGroupItem =
                                          posGroup[posGroupIndex];
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                                20, 0, 20, 10),
                                        child: Material(
                                          color: Colors.transparent,
                                          elevation: 3,
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                          ),
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 100,
                                            height: 100,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Color(0xFF168183),
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(
                                                        context)
                                                    .primaryBtnText,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              child: InkWell(
                                                onTap: () async {
                                                  setState(() =>
                                                      FFAppState()
                                                              .posGroupName =
                                                          getJsonField(
                                                        posGroupItem,
                                                        r'''$..posGroupName''',
                                                      ).toString());
                                                  setState(() =>
                                                      FFAppState()
                                                              .posGroupId =
                                                          getJsonField(
                                                        posGroupItem,
                                                        r'''$..posGroupId''',
                                                      ).toString());
                                                  await Navigator.push(
                                                    context,
                                                    PageTransition(
                                                      type:
                                                          PageTransitionType
                                                              .fade,
                                                      duration: Duration(
                                                          milliseconds: 0),
                                                      reverseDuration:
                                                          Duration(
                                                              milliseconds:
                                                                  0),
                                                      child:
                                                          PointOfServiceWidget(
                                                        parmPOSGroupId:
                                                            getJsonField(
                                                          posGroupItem,
                                                          r'''$..posGroupId''',
                                                        ).toString(),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                child: Column(
                                                  mainAxisSize:
                                                      MainAxisSize.max,
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    AutoSizeText(
                                                      getJsonField(
                                                        posGroupItem,
                                                        r'''$..posGroupName''',
                                                      ).toString(),
                                                      style: FlutterFlowTheme
                                                              .of(context)
                                                          .bodyText1
                                                          .override(
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                'SharpSans',
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .white,
                                                            fontSize: 20,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .w500,
                                                            useGoogleFonts: GoogleFonts
                                                                    .asMap()
                                                                .containsKey(
                                                                    FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                                        .bodyText1Family),
                                                          ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap `AutoSizeText` with `Expanded`:

```
Expanded(
 child: AutoSizeText(/*...*/),
),
```